# Force an activity in a TabSpec to update its view?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a TV Guide activity which extends TabActivity. The tabs are labelled (example)...

```
Today|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun|Mon
```

The TabHost.TabSpec content of each is set to another activity (GuideListActivity) which extends ListActivity like so...

```
private void AddGuideTab(String tag, String indicator, String startDate, String endDate) {
    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, GuideListActivity.class);

    // Set other Intent stuff

    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(indicator).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

This gives me a 7 day list of all the TV shows for one channel. All good so far.

The problem is how to cleanly recreate all of this when the user wants to view another channel's listings....

I have a button which the user can press which creates a popup 'channel selector' dialog. The dialog correctly returns the new channel name/number but I can't figure out how to either remove each TabSpec/GuideListActivity in order to start again nor tell the existing GuideListActivity that it needs to repopulate its ListView.

What am I missing? I seem to be going round in circles reading the docs.

Comment: you have a list with some data listed and on some action of data update you want to update the list view to show the updated data ?. is that you are looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main problem was in how to notify each GuideListActivity that the channel had been changed.

I solved this by creating a nested class in the GuideListActivity which extends BroadcastReceiver and the TabActivity now uses `sendStickyBroadcast();` to send a sticky Intent containing the current channel selection. Each time a GuideListAvtivity is resumed, it can check the sticky Intent and adjust its ListView if the channel selection has changed.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your requirement right then for a single `Activity` that displays a `ListView` . In case of data update if `ListView` need to refresh then on the `Adapter` of `ListView` `notifyDataSetChanged()` function has to be called. This will tell the `ListView` to recreate the view again.

```
((BaseAdapter)(listView.getAdapter())).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you but each GuideListActivity is responsible for its own 'dataset'. I need the main (TabActivity) to tell each of them that they need to perform a new SQL query to update the SimpleCursorAdapter which they use to populate the ListView.

Comment: Maintain the reference of each listview in the TabActivity and after updating all the data after db query call the dataSetChanged on everyone of them.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is that the 'content' of each TabSpec is a ListActivity (not a ListView). I don't want my TabActivity to know anything about the ListActivity's ListView - the TabActivity knows what TV channel the user wants to view and what I need to do is tell each ListActivity that the user wants to view a different TV channel's data so each ListActivity performs a new SQL query and updates its own ListView.

Comment: i wonder what you wanna do. but tell me if i have 5 LIST ACTIVITY any where in the application. And after something i want to update them all. dont you think i have to reset the adapter of all of them one by one. That will be too bad if i generate the entire tab view again from scratch when i have methods for updating the adapters..